# saving state of radio buttons while selection in android

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I am working on and application where my activity has 2 radio buttons.

- 4 channel
- 9 channel

a - default selection of the screen is on 4channel radio button.

b - if user want to click (9channel) button,  it open a dialog box prompting user

" if you move, all saved items will be deleted "

c - In the dialog box i have "Yes" and "No" button. If you click "Yes" button it moved to 9 channel radio button selection.

The issues that i want to fix are :

**1 -**  when user click on "No" button on the dialog box, i quit the dialog.
But selection of radio button still moves to the (9channel) radio button
How to keep the old selection if user click "No" on the dialog box.

**2 -**  Default selection on the activity is on (4channel) radio button. 
      If user click on the same selected button,  i dont want the dialog box to open.
     The dialog box should open only if i click on the other radio button .

How can i achieve the above 2 scenarios.

my Code :

```
rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
public void addListenerOnButton() 
{

   OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
               selection = (String) rb.getText();

                   mFlag = true;
                   showDialog(SELECTION_ALERT_ID);

        }
    };

    RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    rb1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    rb2.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in the code you show. In the scenario you describe, your app is focused in the dialog, so **you must control the action on the dialog**.

First, you dont want to do any action if `rb1` is pressed, so delete this line:

```
rb1.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

After, your dialog code is not shown, so I show you the way I do this usually with some modifications to fit your needs:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            // set's the message to the dialog
            .setMessage("if you move, all saved items will be deleted")
            // accept button
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      dialog.dismiss();
                      // select the 9channel and do the actions
                }
            })
            // cancel button
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      dialog.dismiss();
                }
            // dismiss action (if back button is pressed, same as cancel)
            }).setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                      dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).create();

    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Castella I tried your code. but i still face issue 1 and 2. I am really not able to understand how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ca);
            builder.setTitle("Final Cropped Image");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        //check 9chanel

}
   });
           builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            // check 4chanell

                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: ..can you tell me how to get the view / id of 4channel radio button into the dialog box negative method()

Comment: //---RadioButton---
 RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdbGp1);
 radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
 {
 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
 RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdb1);
 if (rb1.isChecked()) {
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
  "Option 1 checked! ",
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } else {
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
  "Option 2 checked! ",
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 }
 });
 }

Comment: simple example to handle radio button